# Loop cut and slide didn't complete the loop

Tags: modeling, mesh, selection-tools

Not only that, the object is no longer manifold, and I haven't been able to fix it.
[Look at the right side of the loop.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gy6e0cyhe59ghhr/NTrim.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

When a loop cut doesn't complete, it is usually because it hits a triangular face.

Before you did the loop cut, you have a misplaced quadrilateral. On the corner where the cut ends, there is an extra edge. If you move to the bottom corner of the object where the line is, there are two extra vertices.

The image below has the vertices highlighted.

[image: Bad verticies]

Delete these vertices and then try and complete the loop cut.

You have to ensure that no extra faces like in your mesh exist. If a loop cut fails, your mesh will almost always have an error like this or a triangular face.

Good luck with your project and I hope I helped,

BFB

Comment: It's not only tris that stop loops and they are usually easy to spot. ngons are  a more common issue, especially when working in edge select mode.

Comment: Yes, good point @metaphor_set. Hertforkc's model does not have a ngon, but it is a valid thing to look for and one i forgot to mention in my reply

Comment: I noticed the extra vertices  only after I did the loop cut.  Thought  they were the result of the fail and not the cause of it.   Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, no cigar. I just went back to the file which I posted and pulled a copy of the uncut Cyl219W.002 from Object Window 7 and examined it. I didn't find the extra vertices.  Did the Loop Cut and -BOOM- they're back.  Were you able to repair the mesh, finish the loop cut and get a manifold result?

Comment: It was a simple enough repair. Delete the face and the extra vertices, the fill the faces. On your uncut model, are there any internal faces? Just an idea. I just found it odd that such formations appear due to a loop cut. Particularly when no misplaced vertex could be found. Check your normals just in case. Doubt it is the problem but who knows? Send the old file if you can

Comment: Uncut Cyl219W.002 from Object Window 7 was duplicated and moved to Window 1 just prior to the Loop Cut.  I'll recheck per your suggestions.  As far as simplicity of repair, when I deleted the two spurious vertices, there were about a dozen faces to repair, which I did.  Can't say I was happy about that.  I'm running into too many cases where an operation gives rise to stumbling blocks, which may really stop you several steps down the path.  I have no idea how You know where to look for potential causes for error, but it really strains me  to critically examine the mesh after every operation.

Comment: I couldn't find any reason to expect problems when I reexamined the uncut mesh.

Comment: Ok. If you ever come across this incident again, send the file before the loop cut so someone can take a look. See if we can help